# Which words are causing wrong prediction

Tags: classification, nlp

I have a simple multiclass text classification code which uses -
split words -> remove stop words ->apply TFIDF vectorizer -> RandomForest (or LinearRegression or NaiveBayes)

During prediction some sentences which are similar to trained sentences but have some extra words are causing low confidence for a class prediction.
I want to automatically identify those words which contributed to reducing the confidence score. 
Any advice?

Example (2 class prediction): 
I want to know status of this task -> Status Update (0.98 score)
I am working since morning and during and discovered that task status is incomplete so spent extra hours to complete the work. -> Status Update (0.6 score), TaskFinish (0.4 score)

In above hypothetical example, in second sentence, words like "complete" tried to change the class and words like "working", "discovered" etc which are not useful words causing low score for status update. These words I want to identify.